# Sending image to data buffer, but I get a key error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to save a picture into a buffer. For that I'm using the following code:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
buffer = io.StringIO()
img = Image.open(<image_path>)
img = img.resize((640,960), Image.NEAREST)
format = "JPG" # JPG,PNG,etc.
img.save(buffer,format)
```

However, I get `KeyError: 'JPG'`. I've seen several answers using this approach, so I don't know why I'm getting this error. [Here's an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52411503/convert-image-to-base64-using-python-pil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key error you are getting, is because you are passing the string 'JPG' as format.
JPG isn't a valid option in [Pillow's format options](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html). You want to use "JPEG" in this case.

Not passing `format=variable` in this case shouldn't matter, as format is a [valid second positional argument](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/Image.html#Image.save).

Also, be careful. **Format()** is a builtin function in python. Currently you are overwriting that function with a string. It might be better to choose a different variable name, like 'frmt' or '_format'.

So, your code should work by changing the last 2 lines to the following:

```
frmt = "JPEG"
img.save(buffer,frmt)
```

or

```
frmt = "JPEG"
img.save(buffer,format=frmt)
```